# Using exec() and a user defined string - If statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simply for experimentation, I wanted to see if I could make a program in which the user could input strings, which could then be executed as Python code. However, I cannot seem to get if/while/for statements to work properly. So, is there a method of doing this which I am missing?

My source code:

```
prog = []

while True:
    varCommand = input(':')
    if varCommand == 'shell':
        code = ' '
        while code[len(code)-1] != 'end':
            code = [input('>>>>')]
            prog += code
        del prog[len(prog)-1]

    if varCommand == 'run':
        for i in range(len(prog)):
            exec(prog[i])

    if varCommand == 'view':
        for i in range(len(prog)):
            print('>>>>' + prog[i])

    if varCommand == 'delete':
        prog = []
```

For example, if I try to do:

```
for i in range(1,11):
```

attempting to run that with the above program causes a runtime error, due to an EOF, pointing to the colon. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
if varCommand == 'run':
    for i in range(len(prog)):
        exec(prog[i])
```

this using this loop causes the program to run what the user has inputted one line at a time.  So the first `exec` only sees the for loop, and doesn't know that anything is after it.  The `exec` needs to see the entirety of the entered code.

What you want is to execute everything that has been entered at once, with each string separated by a newline.  Replace the above with:

```
if varCommand == 'run':
    exec('\n'.join(prog))
```

So I can now do

```
:shell
>>>>for i in range(10):
>>>>    print(i)
>>>>
>>>>end
:run
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```